# Pandas: Remove all rows where any of the column contains a certain substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is my df:

```
In [1531]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','a','a'], 'B':['all::1::all','all::1::all', '100::1::2', 'm::1::a','all::1::all','c::1::29'], 'C':['0::1::1', '0::1::1', '0::1::1','0::1::1', 'all::1::all', 'all::1::all'], 'D':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

In [1532]: df
Out[1532]: 
   A            B            C  D
0  a  all::1::all      0::1::1  1
1  a  all::1::all      0::1::1  2
2  a    100::1::2      0::1::1  3
3  a      m::1::a      0::1::1  4
4  a  all::1::all  all::1::all  5
5  a     c::1::29  all::1::all  6
```

I want to remove all rows from `df` which contain the substring `all` in any of the columns.

**I can have any number of columns hence want a generalised solution without having to loop on all columns.**

Expected output:

```
In [1534]: df[~df.B.str.contains('all') & ~df.C.str.contains('all')]
Out[1534]: 
   A          B        C  D
2  a  100::1::2  0::1::1  3
3  a    m::1::a  0::1::1  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for select all strings columns, replace possible missing values, add separator for distinguish end of columns strings, `sum` for join together and last use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
df = (df[~df.select_dtypes(object)
            .fillna('')
            .astype(str)
            .add('|')
            .sum(axis=1)
            .str.contains('all')])
print (df)
   A          B        C  D
2  a  100::1::2  0::1::1  3
3  a    m::1::a  0::1::1  4
```

Comment: It is failing for `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':['all', 1, 2], 'C':[2,'all', 'am']})`. Error is: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` .

Comment: @MayankPorwal - I understand, there are mixed types in some column, so `.astype(str)` is necessary